# find value from json output

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have the following  api output from a url.
I need a specific values for all the 'Zones' from these but i am unable to fetch it .
Could you suggest what i need to change here.

```
dict =[ { "Fabric": "Madgth", "Zones": "rqu_kan23_34334_6666_56713", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:10 40:00:01:65:36:e4:20:ea" }, { "Fabric": "Madgth", "Zones": "rqu_kan23_C9AE9F10_6666_ytr9", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:10 40:00:01:69:36:e4:20:ea" }, { "Fabric": "Madgth", "Zones": "sdgh_5672_kan23_asd0", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:10 40:00:01:62:46:e0:70:bc" }, { "Fabric": "Madgth", "Zones": "fdsf_ytr2_kan23_dsd1", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:10 40:00:01:6a:46:e0:70:t5" }, { "Fabric": "Madgth", "Zones": "asdasd_5673_kan21_sdg0", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:14 40:00:01:63:47:60:04:b2" }, { "Fabric": "Madgth", "Zones": "FGF546_ytr3_kan21_SHQ1", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:14 40:00:01:6b:47:60:04:b2" }, { "Fabric": "sdfsdf", "Zones": "rqu_kan23_C9AE9F11_6666_5678", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:11 40:00:01:60:36:e4:20:ea" }, { "Fabric": "sdfsdf", "Zones": "rqu_kan23_C9AE9F11_6666_ytr12", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:11 40:00:01:6c:36:e4:20:ea" }, { "Fabric": "sdfsdf", "Zones": "FGF1166_5673_kan23_SHQ0", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:11 40:00:01:63:46:e0:70:bc" }, { "Fabric": "sdfsdf", "Zones": "FGF1166_ytr3_kan23_SHQ1", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:11 40:00:01:6b:46:e0:70:bc" }, { "Fabric": "sdfsdf", "Zones": "FGF546_5670_kan21_SHQ0", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:15 40:00:01:60:47:60:04:b2" }, { "Fabric": "sdfsdf", "Zones": "FGF546_ytr0_kan21_SHQ1", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:15 00:00:00:00:47:60:04:b2" } ]
print dict['Zones']
```

i seem to be getting the following error.

> File "test.py", line 3, in 
>       print dict['Zones'] TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Use a list comprehension `[i['Zones']  for i in di]` and do not use `dict` use something else for a variable name, `dict` is a builtin. You have provided  a list and wonder how you got tuple indices.

Comment: That code doesn't produce that error. Instead, it produces a syntax error. Because you have several syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

Here it's list only, You have to do like.

```
dict[0]['Zones']
```

There is an mismatch with your sample and the error message. Sample given as list of dictionaries and error message correspond to a tuple.

To get all `"Zones"` use

```
zones = [i['Zones'] for i in dict if 'Zones' in i]
```

> And please don't use `dict` as variable name.

For the clarification in the comments,

```
In [16]: dict =[ { "Fabric": "Madgth", "Zones": "rqu_kan23_34334_6666_56713", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:10 40:00:01:65:36:e4:20:ea" }, {
    ...:  "Fabric": "Madgth", "Zones": "rqu_kan23_C9AE9F10_6666_ytr9", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:10 40:00:01:69:36:e4:20:ea" }, { "Fabri
    ...: c": "Madgth", "Zones": "sdgh_5672_kan23_asd0", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:10 40:00:01:62:46:e0:70:bc" }, { "Fabric": "Madgth", "
    ...: Zones": "fdsf_ytr2_kan23_dsd1", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:10 40:00:01:6a:46:e0:70:t5" }, { "Fabric": "Madgth", "Zones": "asdasd
    ...: _5673_kan21_sdg0", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:14 40:00:01:63:47:60:04:b2" }, { "Fabric": "Madgth", "Zones": "FGF546_ytr3_kan21_S
    ...: HQ1", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:14 40:00:01:6b:47:60:04:b2" }, { "Fabric": "sdfsdf", "zones": "rqu_kan23_C9AE9F11_6666_5678", "
    ...: Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:11 40:00:01:60:36:e4:20:ea" }, { "Fabric": "sdfsdf", "Zones": "rqu_kan23_C9AE9F11_6666_ytr12", "Member
    ...: s": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:11 40:00:01:6c:36:e4:20:ea" }, { "Fabric": "sdfsdf", "Zones": "FGF1166_5673_kan23_SHQ0", "Members": "00:00:0
    ...: 0:00:c9:ae:9f:11 40:00:01:63:46:e0:70:bc" }, { "Fabric": "sdfsdf", "Zones": "FGF1166_ytr3_kan23_SHQ1", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9
    ...: f:11 40:00:01:6b:46:e0:70:bc" }, { "Fabric": "sdfsdf", "Zones": "FGF546_5670_kan21_SHQ0", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:15 40:00:01
    ...: :60:47:60:04:b2" }, { "Fabric": "sdfsdf", "Zones": "FGF546_ytr0_kan21_SHQ1", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:15 00:00:00:00:47:60:04:
    ...: b2" } ]

In [17]: print dict['Zones']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-cccdb30efad8> in <module>()
----> 1 print dict['Zones']

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: @StefanPochmann Error is an related to tuple only. Please check the variable it's list only know.

Comment: Look out the `dict` which is in the question. It's list of dictionaries.

Comment: He got `TypeError: tuple indices` not `TypeError: list indices`

Comment: That code sample can only produce `TypeError: list indices`. May be wrongly pasted the sample. It's might a tuple like `dict = ({...},{...},)`.

Comment: @RahulKP the question also states `all the 'Zones'` so you might need to update your answer with a list comprehension.

Comment: Again: That code sample doesn't produce **any** type error but a **syntax** error. You don't know how their actual code/data looks like, and the error message clearly says it's a tuple, not a list. It might be something like `dict = [1, 2], [3, 4]`, which is a **tuple**.

Comment: I fixed the dict a little bit and now i don't get any of the errors that you guys are fighting about?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Please check the answer now, It's for your clarification :)

Answer (score 1):

The dict you gave had some errors in declaration , here's the fixed one:

```
dict =[ { "Fabric": "Madgth", "Zones": "rqu_kan23_34334_6666_56713", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:10 40:00:01:65:36:e4:20:ea" }, { "Fabric": "Madgth", "Zones": "rqu_kan23_C9AE9F10_6666_ytr9", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:10 40:00:01:69:36:e4:20:ea" }, { "Fabric": "Madgth", "Zones": "sdgh_5672_kan23_asd0", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:10 40:00:01:62:46:e0:70:bc" }, { "Fabric": "Madgth", "Zones": "fdsf_ytr2_kan23_dsd1", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:10 40:00:01:6a:46:e0:70:t5" }, { "Fabric": "Madgth", "Zones": "asdasd_5673_kan21_sdg0", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:14 40:00:01:63:47:60:04:b2" }, { "Fabric": "Madgth", "Zones": "FGF546_ytr3_kan21_SHQ1", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:14 40:00:01:6b:47:60:04:b2" }, { "Fabric": "sdfsdf", "zones": "rqu_kan23_C9AE9F11_6666_5678", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:11 40:00:01:60:36:e4:20:ea" }, { "Fabric": "sdfsdf", "Zones": "rqu_kan23_C9AE9F11_6666_ytr12", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:11 40:00:01:6c:36:e4:20:ea" }, { "Fabric": "sdfsdf", "Zones": "FGF1166_5673_kan23_SHQ0", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:11 40:00:01:63:46:e0:70:bc" }, { "Fabric": "sdfsdf", "Zones": "FGF1166_ytr3_kan23_SHQ1", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:11 40:00:01:6b:46:e0:70:bc" }, { "Fabric": "sdfsdf", "Zones": "FGF546_5670_kan21_SHQ0", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:15 40:00:01:60:47:60:04:b2" }, { "Fabric": "sdfsdf", "Zones": "FGF546_ytr0_kan21_SHQ1", "Members": "00:00:00:00:c9:ae:9f:15 00:00:00:00:47:60:04:b2" } ]
```

Now a simple code like this will do:

```
list = []
for i in dict:
    list.append(i["Zones"])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply loop the list and print it.

```
for item in dict:
    print item['Zones']
```

It's not recommended to use `dict` as a variable name though ;)